# Monoidal operations on categories where the maps on Aut, End are injective

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose we have a monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$. I am interested in the conditions or situations where the following do and do not hold:

1. For any objects *A*, *B* of $\mathcal{C}$, the induced map $\operatorname{End}(A) \times \operatorname{End}(B) \to \operatorname{End}(A \otimes B)$ is injective (by induced map, I mean the map induced by the bifunctoriality).
2. For any objects *A*, *B* of $\mathcal{C}$, the induced map $\operatorname{Aut}(A) \times \operatorname{Aut}(B) \to \operatorname{Aut}(A \otimes B)$ is injective (this is a restriction of the map in (1)).

(1) is stronger than (2). I think I have a proof that in the case that $\otimes$ is a product or coproduct (i.e., we have a Cartesian or co-Cartesian (?) monoidal category) [EDIT: My proof was wrong, as the counterexamples below show], both (1) and (2) hold, i.e., the maps on the two factors are "determined" by the map on the (co)-product. On the other hand, when $\otimes$ is the tensor product of modules over a commutative unital ring, (1) and (2) need not hold, though I think they do hold when the ring is a field.

So my question is: what are more examples where (1) and (2) do hold, what are more examples where they don't, and are there some other conditions/properties which would imply (1) and (2)?

ADDED LATER: It seems that zero objects provide some immediate counterexamples to (1) and (2) even for the category of sets. So I'm modifying (1) and (2) to the following:

1.' For what objects *A*, *B*, is the induced map $\operatorname{End}(A) \times \operatorname{End}(B) \to \operatorname{End}(A \otimes B)$ injective? i.e., How would we characterize such *A* and *B*? The most general possibility seems to be if it is true for all *A* and *B* that are not initial or final objects.

2.' For what objects *A*, *B*, is the induced map $\operatorname{Aut}(A) \times \operatorname{Aut}(B) \to \operatorname{Aut}(A \otimes B)$ injective? i.e., How would we characterize such *A* and *B*? The most general possibility seems to be if it is true for all *A* and *B* that are not initial or final objects.

Comment: (1) and (2) do not necessarily hold when C is Cartesian, e.g., take C = Set, B = the empty set.

Comment: Neither do (1) and (2) hold for the tensor category of vector spaces over a field, as one can take $B=0$.

Comment: I think I assumed "nonzero" in all cases, in which case it does hold, as discussed in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions don't seem to obtain very often, unfortunately.

Let's begin with the one-object case (where the one object is the unit, as it must be). This is the same thing as a monoid object in monoids, or equivalently, a commutative monoid $A$, by Eckmann-Hilton. Your requirement (1) appears to be that the multiplication $A\times A\to A$ is injective; requirement (2) is the same, applied to the invertible elements. This says that every element of $A$ can be uniquely factored, so that $A$ is trivial. So in the one-object case, (1) happens exactly once, and (2) is equivalent to the nonexistence of nontrivial invertible elements.

Using this, we deduce that the unit in a monoidal category satisfying either (1) or (2) is either *very rigid* in the sense that it admits no nontrivial endomorphisms or, respectively, *rigid* in the sense that it admits no nontrivial automorphisms.

If the category $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object $\varnothing$ that is preserved by the monoidal structure (so that $X\otimes\varnothing=\varnothing\otimes X=\varnothing$ for all $X\in\mathcal{C}$), then every object has to (1) very rigid or (2) rigid. This kills off the bulk of the "algebraic" examples (like modules over a ring, etc.)

Also, note that your conditions are symmetric, i.e., (1) or (2) holds for $\mathcal{C}$ iff it holds for $\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$. So Reid's example showing that not all cartesian categories satisfy (2) also works to show that not all cocartesian categories satisfy (2). (We contemplate the coproduct in $\mathrm{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$...)

I don't want to be overly negative; so here's a situation in which I think your conditions do hold: suppose $\mathcal{C}$ a category with all finite coproducts. Suppose the morphism $X\to X\sqcup Y$ is monic for any $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ (equipped with the coproduct) satisfies your condition. (So this works for finite sets with disjoint union, for instance.) Dually, if  $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with all finite products such that the morphism $X\times Y\to X$ is epic for any $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{C}$ (equipped with the product) satisfies your condition. (So this works for the product on nonempty finite sets, for instance.)

Comment: Thanks! I had naively assumed that the map to the coproduct is always monic and the map from the product is always epic -- but the examples involving zero objects show that this is not the case.